# Run a oneOf validation imperatively?

Tags: express, express-validator

I'm trying to validate a `PATCH` request payload for a Todo App that should have at least a `text` or a `value` property. I'm doing so in `updateTodoValidators`. Both properties are optional but at least one must exist (hence the `oneOf`) and if any exists it must be valid as the validators outside the `oneOf` indicate.

```js
const validate = (validations) => {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    await Promise.all(validations.map(validation => validation.run(req)));

    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
      return next();
    }

    res
      .status(422)
      .json({
        payload: {
          errors: errors.array()
        },
        message: "Validation error/s",
        error: true
      })
  }
}

const updateTodoValidators = [
  oneOf([
    body('text').exists().withMessage('not specified'),
    body('value').exists().withMessage('not specified')
  ]),
  body('text').optional().trim().notEmpty().withMessage('cannot be empty'),
  body('value').optional().isInt({ min: 1 }).withMessage('must be a valid positive number')
]

app.patch('/todos/:id', validate(updateTodoValidators), async (req, res, next) => { /* Route handler implementation */ })
```

I was looking into running the validations imperatively as indicated in [Running validations imperatively [docs]](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/running-imperatively.html) for code readability purposes. And I discovered that if I have some validations that involve a `oneOf` my `validate()` throws with a `TypeError` saying `validation.run` is not a function. Bellow is a stack trace detailing the error:

```
(node:88997) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: validation.run is not a function
    at Promise.all.validations.map.validation (/Users/alejandro/code/Production/server/validators/validate.js:6:64)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/alejandro/code/Production/server/validators/validate.js:6:35
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/alejandro/code/Production/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/alejandro/code/Production/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at loginRequired (/Users/alejandro/code/Production/server/auth/helpers.js:18:24)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/alejandro/code/Production/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/alejandro/code/Production/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/alejandro/code/Production/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/alejandro/code/Production/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
(node:88997) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:88997) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

So, my question is: Is there any way to run validations imperatively when validations might involve one or more `oneOf`s?

Comment: I'm attempting to figure this out too. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing it manually.

Do a `.run()` on both param checks. Then validate the `_errors` property is empty on both.

```
export const validateTokens = async (req, res, next) => {
  // Check to make sure one of the header tokens is set and a UUID
  const token1 = await header('token1')
    .isUUID()
    .run(req);
  const token2 = await header('token2')
    .isUUID()
    .run(req);

  // Manual oneOf
  if (isEmpty(token1._errors) || isEmpty(token2._errors)) {
    return next();
  }

  // Return error results
  res.status(400).send('Must include either token1 or token2');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`oneOf` returns a middleware instance, not a validation chain. It doesn't have a `.run()` function which your customer middleware validator uses to validate hence it is erroring out.

There is an open issue for this [here](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/822)

For the moment I think you would need to implement you own custom function to validate these conditional parameters.